# Is it possible insert a file into the input (type file) from url?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible insert a file into the input (type file) from url or from url add to FileList?

```
<input type="file" id="image" hidden>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not directly.

Windows does allow pasting in an URL in the Open File dialog, but it will download the file to a temporary directory on the client machine and then re-upload it onto your server.

You may want to look into something like https://uppy.io/ if you need both uploading and transloading.

Comment: And what about linux